# Dynamicaly calculate the coordinates of a point in front of a moving object?

Tags: javascript, canvas, geometry

I am working on a web project where I have a car moving on the canvas, and I need to get the colors of the pixels in front of the car. I know how to get their colors, but have problems with their coordinates because my car's angle of moving is changing. Can I somehow dynamically calculate their coordinates knowing the center point of the car and its angle rotation?

[image: How it looks]

Comment: You need to put a lot more details in your question. I assume this in in 2D? How is the car represented? It would also help to show a screenshot of what you have.

Comment: Yep,its in 2D.I added a screenshot.

Comment: That is one part. The other was the representation of the car.

Comment: Yes You can use Math.sin and Math.cos to get the new x,y based on angle and distance.

Comment: @George , distance from what?From the center of the car to the pixel in the front?Can you write the formula?

Comment: yes. the distance from the car center to the front of the car.

Comment: @George , Thanks!It works but a little strange.The pixel isn't in front of the car but on it's right side.

Comment: Then change the angle. The angle needs to be in radians. You can use Math.PI.

Comment: @George , the angle is in radians.I wrote it like this: 
var rot = car.rotation * Math.PI/180;
            zzz = car.x  + Math.cos(rot)*1;
            yyy = car.y + Math.sin(rot)*1;

Comment: @George ,for some reason,x is changing instead of y.The initial position is x=870,y=370.I need the pixel at x=870,y=351,but y remains 370 and x became 889.

Comment: try swapping sin and cos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use sine and cosine like this:

```
function xyFromVector(angle, mag){
  return {
    x: Math.cos(angle)*mag,
    y: Math.sin(angle)*mag,
  }
}

const { x: xd, y: yd } = xyFromVector(carAngle, carLength/2);
//car x + xd = x position of front of car
//car y + yd = y position of front of car
```

angle must be in radians.